# Angular - How to blur the background while typing?

Tags: html, css, angular, autocomplete

I have made a search-box like this[image] where when I enter any character an autocomplete drops down. As you can see the texts behind the autocomplete is completely visible. How do I blur it out, like this [image]

I have tried `filter: blur(30px);` but nothing happened. Tried this
HTML:

```
<div [class.filter]="input.value">
  <div class="form-field d-flex align-items-center">
    <div
      style="width: 3rem; height: 2rem"
      class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
    >
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <input
      #input
      type="text"
      class="input-search flex-grow-1 w-100"
      placeholder="Search for a food item ..."
      [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [class.filter]="input.value">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">
        {{ option.name.en }}
      </mat-option>
      <button class="view-btn mb-2" mat-button *ngIf="options.length > 2" (click)="onClickViewAllResults()">View all results</button>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-field {
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  width: 31rem;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  border-style: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-search {
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  color: rgb(250, 85, 99);
  font-weight: 400;
  &:focus {
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}

.filter{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  &::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
    z-index: 100000;
  }
}

.view{
  padding-left: 10rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.view-btn{
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(237,69,88), rgb(221, 0, 18));
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 0.6rem;
  border: none;
  width: 10rem;
  margin-left: 10rem;
}

mat-icon {
  color: rgba(140, 177, 240, 0.74)
}

mat-autocomplete{
  filter: blur(30px);
}
```

But it didn't work. The above code, blurs the input box instead. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's more easy, As you has a template reference variable in your mat-autocomplete (the `#auto`)

```
<input matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
```

You can use in a div

```
<div [style.filter]="auto.isOpen?'blur(4px)':null">
```

or

```
<div [style.opacity]="auto.isOpen?'.2':null">
```

see a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhropx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html)

**Update**

If you can put the different components under a div that are in the "same place" that the mat-autocomplete, the problem is resolved. If there're no relation between the div and the mat-autocomplete (e.g. one is in a parent and the others in a router-outlet and we can not put the router-outlet under a div) the only is "comunicate" using a service. The service can define a Subject, and the component with
the service declare as public in the constructor

```
//a simple service
import {Subject} from 'rxjs'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MatAutoCompleteService {
  open:Subject<any>=new Subject<any>()
  constructor() {}
}
```

You declare as public

```
   constructor(public dataService:MatAutoCompleteService ){}
```

And use in the mat-autocomplete the events `(opened)`and `(closed)`

```
<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    (opened)="dataService.open.next(true)"
    (closed)="dataService.open.next(false)">
```

It's only subscribe to the subject in the component you need. Or you can use async pipe "wrapping" your component in a div in the way

```
<div *ngIf="{open:dataService.open|async} as open" 
 [style.filter]="open.open?'blur(4px)':null">

    ..here your component..

</div>
```

Another [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhropx-vwhj2s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: In this stackblitz, the texts are in one HTML file. What about when they are in a different components. Then what do I do?

Comment: you can always put your components under a div, is the div witch change the style. The other option is more complex, I update the answer with this another option. I feel that should exist a better solution, but I can not get it

Comment: I was looking at one `@ViewChild`, but I have never used this one. So no idea how to do it

Comment: @ViewChild is to "get" a div or a element "inside" a component, Has no relation with the question

Comment: It worked. Would you mind, upvoting my question. Would be of great help